# Kafka Stream Carry Input Header as it is

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want to preserve Input stream record headers as it is in output topic. How can I achieve this?

Kafka Stream Version: 2.3.1

Using `ProcessorContext.forward()` method.

If anyone can give sample snippet code that will be great.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. By default, input records headers are copied to output records.

Comment: No, its not copying by default.

Comment: That would be a bug then. Record headers are supported since 2.0 release: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-244%3A+Add+Record+Header+support+to+Kafka+Streams+Processor+API -- and there is testing in place: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.3/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/internals/ProcessorTopologyTest.java#L377-L398

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a minimum example so we can fix it?

Comment: Sure I will try to reproduce it. I am taking out value from input record and after some processing forwarding it to output topic.